# Is it mandatory that we need to create "Developer Site" to deploy apps? Or can they be deployed on team site too?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, site-template, app, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am working on sharepoint 2013 APPS. My question is can we deploy apps on a team site or some other site template. Or is that apps are specially designed for developer site only. Meaning, is that apps should be deployed on Developer sites only and not on any other site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an App.. ehm.. Add-In.. Catalog to distribute Add-Ins

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp123530.aspx

A Developer Site is only required if you want to.. develop..

Comment: Yeah that's what, means we compulsory need developer site to develop apps.

Comment: In theory you could develop your app/add-in, publish it to your catalogue, push it to your non-developer site and test. Then just repeat each time you change your app during development. It is much easy to just have a developer site though.

Comment: Is the misconception you think you require a Developer site PER customer?